# Share a folder between three accounts created on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: file-sharing

I created three accounts as follows;

```
sudo adduser Edwin
sudo adduser Mike
sudo adduser Brian
```

Now I would like share a folder between these three accounts so if Mike downloaded an image or a document into the folder, Edwin and Brian can see it and be able to modify it.

All help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! The linked answer suggests that your question is a general Linux question not specific to the Pi and is thus bordering being off-topic. Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 6):

You will have to add those users to a group, and then have that group own the directory. The process is outlined in [this Superuser post](https://superuser.com/a/695186/431062)

Answer (score 1):

If you want an user to be able to access a file or a folder, you need to set the correct permissions for it. 
First of all, you need to create a specific group for the three users.

 Do it like so : `groupadd mygroup` where `mygroup` is the name of the group, for instance `sharingUsers`. 
Then, you need to add your users to the group : `useradd -G mygroup user` where `mygroup` is the group you've just created above. Replace `user` with the user you want to add to the group. In your case, run the command three times with Edwin, Mike and Brian.

Then, make sure the file's owner is one of the user in the group you've creating. Use `chown` the change the ownership of a file or folder (assuming that your file is called myFile). So you would do `chown Edwin myFile`.

The permissions are set up with the command `chmod`.
In your case, you would do `chmod g+rw myFile`. This changes the permissions for the group the file owner is in (`g`). The `+` adds permissions and `rw` stands for read and write. If you want the users to be able to execute the file, use `+x`.

To change a file permission for just one user, use `chmod u+rwx myFile`. This will add all the permissions to the user owning the file.

(Note : Never copy commands from website, type them yourself)